# Visual Studio Mac 2019 XAML comma in UIView.Tag causes null

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

When editing View in the designer for Visual Studio number values are displayed with a comma in the property window. When changes are saved the comma is persisted into the XAML and when parsed at runtime the comma cause the value to return null.

1. Is there a setting that can change this?
2. Is this a known issue?

I am dealing with a set of inherited code that uses FindViewByTag heavily and parts of the application appear to randomly "break" after being edited in the designer and I have traced it down to this comma issue...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTg7P.jpg  My rep is to low to post images.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you will get from a screenshot, but I will add one. It is pretty clear cut: open designer -> Tag -> designer inserts comma -> comma persist to markup -> runtime tag is not handled properly due to comma and is null when read. Fix: edit markup remove comma. Looking for a real solution or I need to report the bug. Either or.

Answer (score 0):

Okey , from screen shot ,I will clearly know where set the comma. I think this is not an issue .From document , **[UIView.Tag Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.views.view.tag?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)** is a type of `nint` .

> An integer that can be used to identify a specific UIView instance.

```
[get: Foundation.Export("tag")]
[set: Foundation.Export("setTag:")]
public virtual nint Tag { get; set; }
```

**So**, here you can not setting value with comma in xaml.

Comment: Perhaps you are misunderstanding the issue. Visual Studio adds the comma to the XAML and this causes the Tag property to not load the value => returns null instead of a valid nint. It is in fact an issue as I can reproduce it and to fix it I have to manually edit the XAML and remove the comma added by Visual Studio. It should not be an issue, but it is. It may be returning zero, but encase you didn't know #define NULL = 0; End of the day it discards the actual value because visual studio adds a comma to the XAML markup.

Comment: @ZekeNaulty Okey , so this should be a issue of VS , you can submit in here. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues After submitting , Remember to share link here.